# Showing the distribution of a poisson process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

A large lump of radioactive material has a long half life. Let $D(t)$ be
the total number of decays which occur in the radioactive material in the period of $t$
hours starting at noon on a particular day. Suppose that $\{D(t) : t > 0 \}$ is a Poisson
process of rate $\mu$.

At noon a counter is placed next to the radioactive material. Each decay is recorded by the counter with probability $p$ independently of whether other
decays are recorded and independently of when decays occur. Let $N(t)$ be the total
number of decays that have been recorded by the counter by time $t$.

Prove that $N(t)$ has a Poisson distribution with mean $\mu pt$.

Initially I thought I could use the following;

$$\mathbb{P}(N(t) = n) = \sum^\infty_{k = 0} \mathbb{P}(N(t) = n | D(t) = k)\mathbb{P}(D(t) = k)$$

And I thought $\mathbb{P}(N(t) = n | D(t) = k)$ is the probability of n recordings, and k-n non recordings which would equal $p^n(1-p)^{k-n}$, or zero if $k < n$.

I couldn't progress further, so I thought of another idea.

*I think I would like to go about setting up a differential equation and showing that the pdf of a Poisson$(\mu pt)$ variable would satisfy such an equation.
$$\mathbb{P}(N(t + h) = n) = \\
\mathbb{P}(N(t + h) = n | N(t) > n)\mathbb{P}(N(t)>n)\\
\mathbb{P}(N(t + h) = n | N(t) = n)\mathbb{P}(N(t)=n)\\
\mathbb{P}(N(t + h) = n | N(t) = n-1)\mathbb{P}(N(t)=n-1)\\
\mathbb{P}(N(t + h) = n | N(t) < n-1)\mathbb{P}(N(t)<n-1)$$
However, I think $\mathbb{P}(N(t + h) = n | N(t) = n)$ is the probability of no recordings in the time interval of h, and I am unable to work out this quantity either.*

Edit: Prefer my original idea at the moment.

Any comments and help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **thinning of a Poisson Process**. Suppose that $\Phi$ is the set of decay points in the real line following Poisson with intensity $\lambda$. 
Note that the expected value of $D(t)$ is equal to $\lambda t$.

The problem with your original idea, which I prefer too, is that the conditional distribution is indeed binomial distribution because you have to choose first $n$ decaying points out of total $k$ points. Following is the correct solution:
$$
\Pr(N(t)=n)=\sum_{m=n}^\infty \Pr(N(t)=n\mid D(t)=m)\Pr(D(t)=m)\\
\sum_{m=n}^\infty \binom{m}n p^n(1-p)^{m-n}\frac{(\lambda t)^me^{-\lambda t}}{m!}\\
\sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac {m!}{n!(m-n)!} ({p}\lambda t)^n\frac{((1-p)\lambda t)^{m-n}e^{-\lambda t}}{m!}\\
=\frac {1}{n!} ({\lambda pt})^n e^{-\lambda p t}.
$$

Comment: Was literally just considering that it was binomial. Such a silly thing to overlook. Many thanks!

Comment: Arash, in your solution the summation has $m = n$. I would have thought it was $m \geq n$. Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: @RB_1994, edited the text! Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, more clear, thankyou!